# AC Compressor running but no cold air?

Tags: honda, ac, civic

I have a 2002 Honda Civic. When I bought the car, the AC compressor was unplugged. I plugged it back in and it did not engage. I checked the pressure and it was a little bit low. I jumped the relay with the pressure gauge on and watched the pressure drop when the compressor kicked on. I added some refrigerant but it eventually leveled out and when I pulled the jumper out, the pressure spiked to 120+ PSI on the low side. The clutch does not engage with the relay though the relay doesn't looked charred or broken externally. Is this a problem with the compressor? It's still not blowing air though it appears to affect the pressure when it is engaged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you only had a gauge on the low side. When you unplugged the jumper, the pressure from the high pressure side was able to flow back over to the low side. This caused your pressure spike.  Were either of the lines cold between the compressor or firewall?  What were the pressures at when it was running? These would be clues that could help diagnose it.